# Python 3 - Decorators execution flow

Tags: python, python-decorators

The below example is taken from python cookbook 3rd edition section 9.5.
I placed break points at each line to understand the flow of execution . Below is the code sample, its output and the questions I have . I have tried to explain my question , let me know if you need further info.

```
from functools import wraps, partial
import logging

# Utility decorator to attach a function as an attribute of obj
def attach_wrapper(obj, func=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(attach_wrapper, obj)
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)
    return func

def logged(level, name=None, message=None):


    def decorate(func):
        logname = name if name else func.__module__
        log = logging.getLogger(logname)
        logmsg = message if message else func.__name__

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            log.log(level, logmsg)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)


        @attach_wrapper(wrapper)
        def set_message(newmsg):
            nonlocal logmsg
            logmsg = newmsg


        return wrapper
    return decorate

# Example use
@logged(logging.DEBUG)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
add.set_message('Add called')
#add.set_level(logging.WARNING)
print (add(2, 3))
```

output is

```
DEBUG:__main__:Add called
5
```

I understand the concept of decorators, but this is confusing a little.

**scenario 1**. When the following line is debugged *@logged(logging.DEBUG)* , we get 
*decorate = .decorate at 0x000000000< memoryaddress >>*

**Question** : why would the control go back to execute the function " def decorate" ? Is it because the "decorate" function is on the top of the stack ?

**scenario 2** :When executing *@attach_wrapper(wrapper)* , the control goes to execute *attach_wrapper(obj, func=None)* and  partial function returns 
    *func =*

**question** : why would the control go back to execute *def attach_wrapper(obj, func=None):* 
 and  how would this time the value for func is *.decorate..set_message at 0x000000000 >
 being passed to the attach_wrapper ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Scenario 1

This:

```
@logged(logging.DEBUG)
def add(x, y):
    ....
```

is the same as this:

```
def add(x, y):
    ....
add = logged(logging.DEBUG)(add)
```

Note that there are two calls there: first `logged(logging.DEBUG)` returns `decorate` and then `decorate(add)` is called.

## Scenario 2

Same as in **Scenario 1**, this:

```
@attach_wrapper(wrapper)
def set_message(newmsg):
    ...
```

is the same as this:

```
def set_message(newmsg):
    ...
set_message = attach_wrapper(wrapper)(set_message)
```

Again, there are two calls: first `attach_wrapper(wrapper)` returns the `partial` object and then `partial(set_message)` is called.

---

## In other words...

`logged` and `attach_wrapper` are not decorators. Those are functions which return decorators. That is why two calls are made: one to the function which returns the decorator and another the the decorator itself.

Comment: Nice explanation.